# Using can in the future

Tags: grammar

Can I use the helping verb *can* in the future?
"I can travel to London tomorrow."
Or I have to use *able to*?
"I am able to travel to London tomorrow."

Comment: You can use 'can' for future events. I can visit you tomorrow. You can drive my car next Sunday.

Answer (score 4):

'Can' is perfectly fine in this context, though it is often used in a 'reserved' manner, by which I mean that someone might well say "I *can* travel to London tomorrow, (but really don't want to.)"

'Can' is not a direct replacement for 'Able to' in all circumstances - it works fine in your example, but to borrow Michael H's example, "You can drive my car" does not mean the same thing as "You are able to drive my car"

Comment: I'm not sure about that *a 'reserved' manner.* It seems to me the "reserved, cautious, tentative, provisional" sense is more naturally conveyed with the explicitly "non-Present" form *I **could** travel to London tomorrow (but I'd rather not)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yeah, 'Reserved' in its normal sense isn't the word I was scrabbling for, but still can't think of the right one!

Comment: In formal English, that second sense of "can", conveying permission rather than ability, is instead handled by "may".

Comment: @MontyHarder: I'd say that usage is more "dated" than "formal". *I asked the boss if I **might** leave work early* isn't something you're likely to hear today (it's always ***...if I could***).

Answer (score 2):

English doesn't really have a Future Tense anyway, but I would say that in *I can go tomorrow*, ***can*** is effectively ***Present Tense***. You can see this at the *syntactic* level by noting that the "future" version of *I **can go*** is *I **will be able to** go*.

But it's also true at the *semantic* level, in that ***I can*** go tomorrow effectively means ***My current status is that I will be able to*** go tomorrow. That "present tense reference to future ability" may be more obvious if we also consider *negating* contexts...

> *[My mother's dementia is getting worse...]*
>    1: *... I hope she **will be able** to recognise me next Christmas*
>    2: *... I'm afraid she **won't be able to** recognise me next Christmas* *(**won't** = **will not**)*
>    3: *... I hope she **can** recognise me next Christmas*  (QUESTIONABLE - see below)
>    4: ** *I'm afraid she **can't** recognise me next Christmas*  (INVALID)

Most native speakers would accept the "Present as Future" usage in #3 - particularly if extended to *...can **still** recognise me* (which more overtly references the passage of time between now and next Christmas).

But note that most native speakers would ***not*** accept #3 if we change ***I hope...*** to ***The doctor says...*** That's because my *specific* example refers to *[future] **ability***. In a structurally / syntactically identical example where the meaning is more about *[present / future] **permission***, there's no real difference between...

> 5: *The doctor says I **can** go home tomorrow*
>    6: *The doctor says I **will be able to** go home tomorrow*

---

Because it's both a ["defective"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb) verb (with an incomplete conjugation) ***and*** a ["modal"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/modal_verb) (auxiliary verb expressing necessity or possibility), ***can*** is a difficult word to master in English. There's too much to cover in a single Answer here on ELL, but I'll just point out that in most contexts, the meanings of...

> 7: *The doctor said I **can** go home tomorrow*
>    8: *The doctor said I **could** go home tomorrow*

...are identical. But *sometimes*, #8 means ***...might*** be able, not ***...will*** be able or ***...will be permitted***.

Comment: Thanks all for good information. I understand now it is right to say:

Comment: Thanks so no difference between. I will be able to travel tomorrow And I can travel tomorrow.

Comment: @Sdg: Normally there's also no difference with *I **am** able to travel tomorrow*. Mostly these are just stylistic choices, with no particular syntactic or semantic implications.